# Error with axios receiving data from local server

Tags: reactjs, axios

This is my nodejs code that I am running trying to get data from und.com and then get the output to my react code. I am having an issue with axios trying to pull in the data.

```
const express = require("express");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Connected to react");
    res.redirect("/");
})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;

const website = "https://und.com";

let options = {
headers: {
    "user-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
}
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
// Make the HTTP request using axios
axios(website, options)
.then(({data}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const result = $(".post__meta h3 a:last-child")
    .map((_, e) => $(e).text().trim())
    .get();
    console.log(result);
    // Use cheerio to manipulate the HTML data

    // Set the content type of the response to "text/html"
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");

    // Send the HTML data as the response
    res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // The HTTP request failed
        console.log("An error occurred:", error);
    
        // Set the status code of the response to indicate an error
        res.status(500);
    
        // Send an error message as the response
        res.send("An error occurred while making the HTTP request.");
    });
    })

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on PORT: ${PORT} `);
})
```

Below this is my react app trying to pull the data that is outputted in

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:3002";

const Home = () => {
return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${url}`,

    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    json: true
})
    .then((response) => {
    console.log("POST response: ", response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log("POST error: ", err);
    });
};


export default Home;
```

however I am getting an axios error trying to pull this data in. axios error ERR_NETWORK.

Comment: If you check the Network tab of the browser - what will you see? Also, is the protocol in the url of your React app `https`? If yes - you cannot make http calls from https site.

Comment: Next question - why in React app you are targeting "http://localhost:3002" url using method: "post", in node it will be "/" which is registered as `.get` as i can see.

Comment: I honestly dont know what I am doing. I am just looking to get the data and display it I dont care how I do it.

Comment: 1) You've got no request content so don't need a content-type header. 2) Axios does not have a `json` option. 3) Your Express route uses GET but your request is using `method: "post"`